# Could not find compiled resource bundle 'messaging' for locale 'en_US'. while migrating from 4.0 to 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, resourcebundle

When migrate flex SDK from 4.0 to 4.6. I meet such an error in runtime.

```
 Error: Could not find compiled resource bundle 'messaging' for locale 'en_US'.
 at mx.resources::ResourceManagerImpl/installCompiledResourceBundle()
 at mx.resources::ResourceManagerImpl/installCompiledResourceBundles()
 at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/installCompiledResourceBundles()
 at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/docFrameHandler()
 at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/docFrameListener()
```

The resouce bundle 'mesaging' is included in rpc, and 'rpc' has been loaded to 'caching' while open my app. I found some workround on net, but none does work. I tried:

```
1.add [ ResourceBundle( "messaging" )]
2.decalare a usage to class that maybe use the 'mesaging', such as
 import mx.messaging.channels.HTTPChannel;
 private var httpChannel:HTTPChannel;</pre>
3.In pom
    <includeResourceBundles>
    <bundle>messaging</bundle>
    </includeResourceBundles>
```

Anybody has other solution about the problem? Thanks

Comment: I set the compile option -keep-generated-actionscript=true, and get a folder "generated", in which I find the generated messaging class "messaging_properties.as" and other resource-bundle class in Flex SDK. But in my main app, when I try to get the class definition by ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition("messaging_properties"), the return is false. It's really wierd. I can get other rb class such as "components_properties" by this way.

Comment: I have found the reason. In flash builder -> property -> Flex Build Path, uncheck the option "Remove unused RSLs". It works. It seems like the flex compiler remmove the 'rpc' in my app. Unfortunately, I use flexmojos maven plugin 3.8, and it has no this param. So I have to upgrade to 4.0-RC2